# How can I access and use a return value from a do while loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, return-value, do-while

I am trying to access return data from a do while loop, but I am unable to do so.

I have stored the information in a new variable (starships) and then returned this variable, but it says starships is not defined. I see that this may be a scoping issue, how can I resolve this?

```
async function getData() {

    const allResults = [];
    let url = 'https://swapi.co/api/starships/';

    do {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const data = await res.json();
        url = data.next;
        allResults.push(...data.results);
        console.log(allResults);
    } while (url !== null)

    let starships = allResults;
    return starships;
}

console.log(starships);
```

Comment: Do you mean `let starships = await getData(); console.log(starships);` ?

Comment: You need access it as `getData().then(starships => console.log(starships));`

Comment: @danh `await` can be called without async..So `let starships = await getData();` is not valid.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - The OP declares the function async. See the working answer below from OliverRadini, which is exactly as I suggested.

Comment: @danh Oliver wrapped it inside a function `async function doTheDo() {` which is correct. Your comments seems like you are doing it on top level. I had a typo **`await can be called without async.`** should be **`await can not be called without async.`**

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value which is returned from `getData`. The most obvious way to do this with the `async/await` structure you have is to just `await` it:

```js
async function getData() {
    const allResults = [];
    let url = 'https://swapi.co/api/starships/';

    do {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const data = await res.json();
        url = data.next;
        allResults.push(...data.results);
        console.log(allResults);
    } while (url !== null)

    let starships = allResults;
    return starships;
}

async function doTheDo() {
  const test = await getData();
  
  console.dir(test);
}

doTheDo();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.  starships is defined inside the loop. Additionally, you are not calling   `getData()` function. You can store that return value like this

```
const result = await getData();
console.log(result);
```

or you can directly print like this. `console.log(await getData())`

```
  async function getData() {

    const allResults = [];
    let url = 'https://swapi.co/api/starships/';

    do {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const data = await res.json();
        url = data.next;
        allResults.push(...data.results);
        console.log(allResults);
    } while (url !== null)


    return allResults;
}

console.log(await getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

Async functions return a promise, which means you have to access the return value with a `.then()`.

However, you have another problem: starships is in the scope of the function `getData()` which you have defined, but not called.

So first lets call your function:

```
async function getData() {
    const allResults = [];
    // do stuff
    let starships = allResults;
    return starships;
}

console.log(getData());
```

Now you will see that your log value is `[object Promise]` which isn't so helpful in its current form. This is because the code outside the async function is running synchronously, which means we don't have the value yet, just a promise to maybe return the value sometime in the future.

So now we need to access the promise asynchronously using the `.then()` like so:

```
async function getData() {
    const allResults = [];
    // do stuff
    let starships = allResults;
    return starships;
}

getData().then(starships => {
  console.log(starships);
});
```

Now you should see the info you were expecting to be logged.

You can also save promise to a variable and pass it around and access it elsewhere in your code like so:

```
async function getData() {
    const allResults = [];
    // do stuff
    let starships = allResults;
    return starships;
}

let starshipPromise = getData();

// time & code passes...

starshipPromise.then(starship => {
    console.log(starship);
}).catch(error => {
  // handle error
});
```

And don't forget to catch your rejected promises!

See the MDN docs on Async functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

And if you need more info on promises, go here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise